# Rollbacking changes in XML Document

Tags: c#, xml

I Want to raise an event to prevent any modification on the Xml file.

Simply raising an event is enough ? like

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"d:\XMLFiles\namespace.xml");
doc.Changed +=new EventHandler<XObjectChangeEventArgs>(doc_Changed);
```

What is the code do i need to write inside `doc_changed(..,...)` to rollback any modifications?

```
    static void doc_Changed(object sender, XObjectChangeEventArgs e)
    {

        //what is the code needed here..?  

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than subscribing to `Changed`, you should subscribe to `Changing` so that you get notified *before* it happens.

The easiest way to prevent the change is to throw an exception... but that's quite a severe way of handling it. What situation are you really trying to prevent? Accidental changes due to a developer not understanding that this document is meant to be read-only?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean... are you referring to the Real World Functional Programming book? If so, I only helped out a little - Tomas Petricek did the vast bulk of the work.